# hot wire anemometry

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer

Hot wire anemometry can be used to measure the temperature of a wire in fluid flow. The voltage fluctuation across the wire is used in conjunction with an energy balance on the wire to obtain the temperature. Why is it not a better idea to just measure the resistance change directly and use the material's resistivity temperature coefficient to find the temperature of the wire? That way you wouldn't be relying on empirical Nusselt correlations. What am I missing here?

Comment: No you are right, this method is called constant current method, the first method you did describe is called the constant temperature. Your suggestion makes the instrumentation a bit complicate but it's how for instance strain gauge works.

Comment: You can't measure the resistance of the wire unless you pass a current through it, and because you want to use a very fine wire to get rapid response to temperature changes, the electrical heat generation in the wire ($I^2R$) needs to be accounted for, whatever method you use.

Comment: @alephzero that is not the point here, the change of resistance in 'constant current ' is measured by wheatstone bridge, then the response goes through an instrumentation amplifier and ... . The current here could be about some micro amps so i don't follow you when you talk about resistive heat loss, however in other method the current can reach up to some mA, then you are right.

Comment: @SamFarjamirad I'm familiar with the constant current method. Why can't I hook up a very precise resistance measuring device and relate that directly to resistivity and temperature.

Comment: @omar to my understanding that's exactly how constant current works. In constant current the change in resistance is measured and in constant temperature the change or the rate of voltage fluctuation.

Comment: Got it. I’ll look into it some more. Thanks.